# Why would the compiler use a virtual call for `datum::rotate()` below?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

On page 26 of "Inside the C++ Object Module" by S. Lippman, you'll find the following snippet:

```
void rotate(
X datum,
const X *pointer,
const X &reference )
{
    // cannot determine until run-time
    // actual instance of rotate() invoked
    (*pointer).rotate();
    reference.rotate();
    // always invokes X::rotate()
    datum.rotate();
}
main() {
    Z z; // a subtype of X
    rotate( z, &z, z );
    return 0;
}
```

and this paragraph:

`The two invocations through pointer and reference are resolved dynamically. In this example, they both
invoke Z::rotate(). The invocation through datum may or may not be invoked through the virtual
mechanism; however, it will always invoke X::rotate().`

AFAIK, `datum.rotate()` will always be invoked with a static call. Why would the compiler use a virtual call here?

Comment: Could be interesting theoretically, but people passing a polymorphic type by value in real code should be "re-educated".

Answer (score 0):

The compiler MAY choose to use a virtual call even though doing so is not necessary. The standard does not say that the compiler "MUST" convert it to a static call. As long as the "right" function is called, the compiler has done it's job.

Edit: It would appear that the standard (at least n3337) doesn't say exactly how the compiler is supposed to be called - it basically just says that

> Note: The interpretation of the call of a virtual function depends on the type of the object for which it is
>   called (the dynamic type), whereas the interpretation of a call of a non-virtual member function depends
>   only on the type of the pointer or reference denoting that object (the static type) (5.2.2). — end note